# Lotusscript: Problem to convert an Array into a String

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I have a problem when I try to convert my Array into a comma-separated String. In the example below, I retrieve all the files in my email and send them to my server to add them. My server sends me back an ID that is stored in the Array. Then I try to convert this Array into a String.

```
    Dim filesId(1 To 100) As String
    Dim tmpString As String
    Dim count As Integer
    count = 0

    Set db = Session.Currentdatabase
    Set CurrentDocColl = db.Unprocesseddocuments 
    Set doc = CurrentDocColl.Getfirstdocument
    While Not doc Is Nothing
        Set item = doc.GETFIRSTITEM("Body")
        If doc.HasEmbedded Then
            ForAll attachment In item.EmbeddedObjects
                jsonBody="value={""filename"":"""+attachment.Name+"""}"
                    
                Set http=session.CreateHTTPRequest()
                http.preferstrings = True

                Call http.SetHeaderField("ContentType","application/json")

                ret = http.Post(url, jsonBody)
                    
                If IsNumeric(ret) Then
                    count = count + 1
                    filesId(count) = ret
                Else
                    MessageBox ret
                End If
            End ForAll
        End If
        Set doc=CurrentDocColl.Getnextdocument(doc)
    Wend
    ForAll itemValue In filesId
        If CStr(itemValue ) <> "" Then
            If tmpString = "" Then
                tmpString = itemValue 
            Else
                tmpString = tmpString & "," & itemValue 
            End If
        End If
    End ForAll
    MessageBox tmpString
```

The problem is that the final String contains only the first value of the array and not the next values.

> **Example with this Array:** [3567,3568,3569,3570]
>
> **Desired result String:** 3567,3568,3569,3570
>
> **Result received:** 3567

I don't understand where this problem comes from, especially since it also doesn't work with the Join() and Implode() functions.

---

**EDIT**

Indeed after having looked in the debugger, we can see that my data are present in the Array but in a particular format because the quotes of the strings do not close. What can I do to fix this?

[image: filesId in the debugger]

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Do you know for sure that the `filesId` array really contains those values before trying to turn it into a string? I suggest using the LotusScript debugger to confirm that. If the `Join` function also doesn't work, that strongly suggests that your array doesn't contain what you think it does.

Comment: Please provide a working code. Your code in question shows a syntax error (`End If` without a related `If`) and a semantic error (FORALL alias variable was previously declared: ITEM). Your last ForAll-Loop works well when a valid filesId array is provided.

Comment: Did you do a Messagbox cstr(count) before the forall loop? Did the loop really run through 4 times?

Comment: @ScottLeis I just edited my question with the result of my debugger, the data is stored in my Array but doesn't seem to be stored correctly (see in the question)

Comment: @KnutHerrmann Sorry the End If was too much in my code, I removed it. About the variable item present in the last loop, if I change the name of the variable, it has no impact on the result. Thank you for reporting this to me

Comment: @TorstenLink Yes, I made it and for it all look fine. I just edited my question with the result of the debugger. In this example, I have only 2 attached files in my email and both of them are in my Array, however it seems to have a problem with the format of the data stored in my Array.

Comment: Your code works for me now. The only thing I replaced for test purposes: `ret = count` instead of `ret = http.Post(url, jsonBody)`.

Comment: For me too, if i make this change, it work! But i think the problem come from my post. From my post, I receive just an ID send from php code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your http post result contains line break at its end. That is why the string looks so "strange" in debugger. This resuls in the following tmpString:

"3267
,3268
,3269
,3270"

Messagebox is not able to show all line breaks... so it only shows the string until the first line break.

You need to remove line breaks from your string before concatenating:

```
Dim badChars(2) as String
Dim goodChars(2) as String

badChars(0) = Chr$(0)
badChars(1) = Chr$(10)
badChars(2) = Chr$(13)

...

filesId(count) = Replace( ret, badChars, goodChars )
```

As I do not know WHICH line break / carriage return is there in your string I replace the three most common ones with blank in above code... Might be another unprintable character in there that you have to get rid of, then you need to examine `Right( ret , 1)` and check, what is in there and replace that.

Comment: It work for me. Thank you for your precious help and your time!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a dim statement for tmpString. If there is no dim, then it is a variant. If it is a variant, then your assignment `tmpString = item` is dynamically defining tmpString as a numeric type. That would cause your assignment `tmpString = tmpString & "," & item` to fail. Since you appear to be expecting numeric data for ret, and you are assigning that into the filesId array, and item is a value from filesId, you need to be using CStr(item) in both of your assignments.

Comment: The numeric data seems unlikely to be a problem, because the `filesId` array is declared as a string, which should mean that `item` in the `ForAll` loop should always be a string. However I don't have any other ideas except debugging.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I edited my code to make it clearer. My variable tmpString is of type String and so I don't think that's the problem.